# linq left outer join object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i am using left outer join in this query below. the variable fgi is coming null so so the line after that in where it giving object reference error. how can solve it?.

```
 var a = (from e1 in _db.Features.ToList()                                             
                                         where e1.int_ParentId==0 && e1.bit_IsModule == true & e1.bit_ShowInMenu == true && e1.bit_Activate == true                                
                                         join e2 in _db.OrganizationModules on e1.int_FeatureId equals e2.int_FeatureId into fg
                                         from fgi in fg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         where fgi.bit_OrganizationModuleActiveDeactive != false && fgi.int_OrganizationId == SepiaCMS.Models.Security.Authorization.OrganizationID   // object reference not set to instance of an object                                                                                   
                                         orderby e1.int_FeaturesSortID ascending, e1.int_FeatureId descending
                                         select new FeatureViewModel
                                         {
                                             featureid = e1.int_FeatureId,
                                             featurename = e1.vcr_FeaturesName,
                                             classes = path == e1.vcr_LinkName ? "<li class=active>" + Html.ActionLink(e1.vcr_FeaturesName, e1.vcr_LinkName.Substring(e1.vcr_LinkName.IndexOf('/') + 1), e1.vcr_LinkName.Substring(0, e1.vcr_LinkName.IndexOf('/')), new { area = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e1.vcr_Area) == true ? "" : e1.vcr_Area }, new { @class = e1.vcr_CssClass }) + "</li>" : "<li>" + Html.ActionLink(e1.vcr_FeaturesName, e1.vcr_LinkName.Substring(e1.vcr_LinkName.IndexOf('/') + 1), e1.vcr_LinkName.Substring(0, e1.vcr_LinkName.IndexOf('/')), new { area = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e1.vcr_Area) == true ? "" : e1.vcr_Area }, new { @class = e1.vcr_CssClass }) + "</li>"
                                         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing a left join i guess you want to include the null values. Just add

```
where fgi == null || (....)
```

Or if you don't want the null values just change the query to an inner join.